# Docker image having apscheduler does not run at all

Tags: python, docker, apscheduler, docker-run

I am new to docker, so bear with me on this.

I have a `app.py` file, which simply uses `apscheduler` to print a sentence on the console. I have followed the structure from the [official guide](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/master/examples/schedulers/background.py) for the python file. When I run the file on my console, it runs as expected. (prints the Tick statement every 10 seconds.)

Now, I want to dockerize it and upload the image to dockerhub. I followed the docker documentations and this is how my `DockerFile` looks like:

```
FROM python:3
COPY requirements.txt .
COPY app.py .
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

I have listed the module names in `requirements.txt` as below:

```
datetime
apscheduler
```

The folder is flat. `app.py` and `requirements.txt` are in the same level in the directory.

```
|
|- app.py
|- requirements.txt
```

I use below commands to build the docker image:

```
docker build . -t app1:ver3
```

The docker image builds successfully and shows up when I do

```
docker images
```

Problem is, when I run the docker image with

```
docker run app1:ver3
```

the image does not show any output.

In fact the image shows as listed when I do `docker ps` - which is expected but the run command should show me print statements on the console every 10 seconds.

Comment: Did you try `docker run -it app1:ver3`

Comment: See this also https://tarunlalwani.com/post/why-delayed-output-python-docker/

Comment: Okay, that worked like a charm. Can you point me to the docs for `-it` ?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/ -> under foreground. -i keeps it it stdin active and -t provisions a tty for it

Comment: i have the same problem then i use APScheduler lib in docker container they don't show output data but if i launch script file inside working container (docker exec -it bac69ce428cc bash; python app.py) all is good, did you find answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things here

You need to use `docker run -it app1:ver3`

```
-i: Interactive mode
-t: Enable TTY
```

I believe just `-t` also may do the job. See the link below for details

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/